# What triggers my Preloader gif to show on Page, while Page is loading?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hi I am trying to display a .gif while a page is loading new content. I understand Ajax, javascript, jquery, but I confused as to how to make this happen.

Here is the div with the gif ...

```
<div id="Loading">
             <div style="display: none;" id="overlay"></div>
                <div id="popup" style="display:none;">
                    <img alt="Loading Rates" src="/Images/loading2.gif" />
                    <div class="dialogtext">Loading available rates, this may take a moment.</div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Here is some JavaScript I wrote some of it works:

I just do not know how to trigger this, and help or reference would be appreciated

Comment: your JavaScript seems to be missing in action :D

Comment: I know ... for some reason the question got submitted without it.

Answer (score 0):

So you want to show the loader gif when an AJAX request is pending?

The most basic event handlers you can use for this are

```
// Attach loading icon show/hide to Ajax events
$(document).on({
    ajaxStart: function () {
        $('#MyLoadingDiv').show();
    },
    ajaxStop: function () {
        $('#MyLoadingDiv').hide();
    }
});
```

And just change your parent div to start with `display: none` (or just tamper with the show/hide calls to suit your specific needs)

There are a number of permutations of this. If you want to attach the loader to just one ajax call (let's say you're using many ajax calls and you only want the loader for one), you can do something like:

```
var myAjaxRequest = $.ajax({
// Your ajax stuff here
    beforeSend: function () { $('#MyLoadingDiv').show(); }
}

$.when(myAjaxRequest).done(function (){
    $('#MyLoadingDiv').hide();
}
```

Off the top of my head, I think you should also just be able to put `{ $('#MyLoadingDiv').show(); }` immediately before the ajax call and hiding it when the request is done.

If there are multiple requests, you might want to do some variation of the above code to the effect of:

```
var myAjaxRequests = []
myAjaxRequests.push($.ajax({
// Your ajax stuff here
    beforeSend: function () { $('#MyLoadingDiv').show(); }
});

$.when.apply($, myAjaxRequests).done(function (){
    $('#MyLoadingDiv').hide();
}
```

The purpose of `apply()` is just split up the array into individual arguments. If you're just using a few Ajax requests you probably don't need the array, you can just pass them all in, but for larger numbers it's nice.

I just hacked out this code in browser so there might be small errors, but it's similar to what I've used to accomplish (I think) exactly the functionality you're looking for.

Comment: Thank you so much ... I will try all of these.

Comment: Hi, I want to clarify that I don't have an ajax call ... my page is loaded from the codebehind, so is there anyway I can use this code that way. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What are you using for the codebehind? If it takes time to load, there's probably a way to link it up to when().

Comment: It is just a static method, triggered by the btnclick          public void LoadSalesData()

Comment: Hi, I got the preloader .gif to work when I press the submit button, works great, but I also need it to work when the user presses <NEXT> page on the gridview control, so in other words, I need it to work whenever the page is reloaded, any tips?

Comment: javascript : document.on ('submit' 'form1', $(id).show(), and document.on ('load', 'form1', $(id).hide()